# How to Download all the link by one download button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, download

Iam writing a website with asp.net mvc4. I have to write a module that user can download all the pdf file by click a download all button.

But the problem is all the pdf file are not already in server. The process run when the action link was call, it export the pdf from html by Rotativa library in asp.net and send back to the browser.

I have the action links were contained by a tags, which were list below the download all button. 
So what I want is when I click a download all button, it will call one by one action link to download the pdf.

Is this possible at all? Any suggestions on how to go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to download 'one by one', since the download procedure is handled by the browser, not your web page.

You may try to

1. Package all the pdf files into a zip on server side.
2. Use some hack like [Detect when browser receives file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download)